# Using a broken Linksys WMP54G radio

Tags: soldering, wireless, connector, repair

I have a Linksys WMP54G v 4.1 Wireless PCI card from an old computer I would like to use it for something but I have a problem.

The end that the antenna attaches to is broken (See picture). I was wondering if I could somehow attach a new end to it? I have a connector I think is called an N connector, I know it better as RP-TNC. The card had an RP-SMA connnector. Is it possible to solder the connector to the broken one? (See Pictures).

[Picture1](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/200/imag0006ko.jpg/)
[Picture2](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/854/imag0007up.jpg/)
[Picture3](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/577/imag0008w.jpg/)
[Picture4](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/12/imag0009fu.jpg/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - that will probably work OK (there may be some inovious gitch but should be no technical problem.).

Very importantly though - you want good mechanical support for the nw larger connector. A non conductove brack (eg plastic) that supports the connector and is screwed to the PCB in a neutral location is advisable. Or Heath Robinson solution is to pot the connector and PCB with eg epoxy resin ;-(.

Ensure shortest possible connections between old and new centres connecyor and good ground to ground connections.

Note that the new connector does not have to point in the same direction as the old one.

- **Mounting it at 90 degrees on a sheet of plastic that extends from the PCB may be extremely effective.**

Even if it is at an angle it can work OK. Shortness of connection length is more important than prettiness.

---

There are several physical ways to connect.

(1) Either connect middle to middle and brass cube to body. This should be very easy to trial with the new connector at an angle so that relevant parts touch. Not pretty but should work OK for trialing.
or

(2) Remove brass cube and connect inner to inner, outer to where body connected 
or

(3) Connect from bottom of PCB with old brass block still in place.

Any of these schemes may produce an impedance step and cause reflections and some loss of signal. But all may work OK - there's a degree of luck involved.

Comment: Is the missing part where the antenna screwed to some kind of ground I am guessing?

Comment: The wire extending out of the middle is the antenna connection - it connects to he middle of the new connector. The solid metal block is ground - it connects to the outer of the new connector. You can remove the old connector (*carefully*) or leave it in place and add the new connector to the old. There MAY be more of an "impedance bump" if the old connector is left in place.

Comment: So you are saying I could remove the old brass cube from around the connector?

Comment: Either connect middle to middle and brass cube to body. This should be very easy to trial with the new connector at an angle so that relevant parts touch. Not pretty but should work OK for tialing.